# Machine Learning Classification and predication in weka

Tags: classification, weka, prediction

I am very new to machine learning. Sorry if there are any mistakes in my English.

I am using the weka J48 Classification for prediction in true or false. I have almost 999K training set which i used to train the model. I used the cross validation method with 3 folds to train the Model which gives me accuracy of ~84%.

Now after storing the model. i tried to test it on 50k dataset. which is giving very bad results and 50% of them are mismatch. I have 11 attributes with nominal and numeric fields.

I dont know why its happening.

I have two questions.

1. How can i train to perform better on test set.
2. what could be possible issues.

I am using weka api in java.

Comment: How did you choose the 50K set to test?

Comment: Actually, i am using 30 days of data of training and 1 day of data for testing and predicting.

Comment: How are you obtaining the 1 day of test data?

Comment: i am getting in CSV file which i am then converting to ARFF.

Answer (score 2):

It means that your model is [overfit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting) for your 999k training set and doesn't generalize well to your 50k testing set.

You should look into cross-validating with (a good portion, but not all) of your 50k dataset in addition to your 999k.

You may also want to try something higher than a k=3, k-fold crossvalidation, because k=3 folds may be too "coarse". Good luck!

Comment: Thank you,  i am using 1/3rd of 999K to test on 2/3rd and then using testing dataset to predict. What exactly you suggest. Can you please elaborate a little more. How can i handle this over fitting issue. I thought the more data i have for training the better result i will get.

Comment: (reading the comments above) Your one day of data for testing & prediction, doesn't "behave" like the previous 30 days used to train. So how about you use a mixture of data from all days, separating by AM/PM or by hour? that way any characteristics of that one day you use for testing/prediction, can also be modeled/trained correctly.  You also may want to ask more specific questions on a machine-learning specific forum. Cheers!

Comment: I am trying to predict the future results based on model build on historic data. So, I cannot mix these two. Can you please suggest some tool which can handle huge datasets for decisions trees if you know. Thanks once again, Cheers

Comment: I personally use http://scikit-learn.org/stable/ , but I don't think your tool or your data size is the problem, fundamentally you have to ask if how you are modelling makes sense, are you capturing the right features and date ranges that makes your model good for prediction (of future results). If today is VERY different from tomorrow using the features you've trained with today, you'll not be able to predict reliably tomorrow. You want to go for features and a model which generalize well. Best of luck